# How can I achieve the same collapsing toolbar with parallax effect as seen in Resplash in my Jetpack Compose app?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

How to implement collapsing toolbar with parallax effect in jetpack compose?

Hi everyone. I want to implement the scrolling behavior like user profile in Resplash application(shown in the link below) in jetpack compose. I want the toolbar be fixed and don't scroll but the information part scroll with parallax effect.
I tried using Box and Scaffold but i didn't achieve the desired result.
Can anyone help me please? I spent 3days on it but couldn't solve.

https://file.io/BaWFLFRIr6X6

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.